# C# display arraylist contents on main application with selection

Tags: c#

I have a form with a text box for a user to enter a search string for folder names.
The app then finds matching folder(s) on the network.

If a single folder is returned it opens in explorer.

If multiple folders are returned in the search they are added to an array as a unc path.

I need to know the best way or which object to use to populate the contents of the array with on the main form.
I then need to be able to double click on the desired result to open the containing folder in explorer to handle multiple matches.

searching for match1
array could contain something like: H:\match1, G:\Match1, K:\folder1\Match1

Comment: i suggest to use a combobox to populate with the array of pathnames, when the user clicks on one of the paths use the selection-changed action to open it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your intentions correctly, a simple ListBox should do. You can handle each path in your array as one list entry and listen to the double click to open the explorer window.

To fill the listbox you could utilize the datasource attribute:

```
    string[] paths = new string...

    // fill array

    yourListBox.DataSource = paths;
```

Addendum: To react to the double click simply listen to the double click event of the list box and in the event handler, do something like this:

```
 private void yourListBox_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     openExplorerWindow((string)yourListBox.SelectedItem);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ArrayList paths = new ArrayList();
        paths.Add("path1");
        paths.Add("path2");
        paths.Add("path3");
        paths.Add("path4");

        foreach (string test in paths)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(test);
        }
    }

    private void listBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        string path = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
```